# Creating a timer that runs in the background

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, timer, background

I'm making a client/server program and on the client I want a clock on the GUI that displays the running time. Now there's plenty of tutorials on here on how to make a clock/timer and I think I have that part down.

The issue is making one that runs in the background while the rest of the code executes. At the moment I have a loop for my timer that the code doesn't move past, so it just starts counting the timer then doesn't do anything else after that. At least until the timer is stopped anyway.

I'm guessing I need to find a way to make it run in the background, but I don't know how and I can't find the answer. It has been suggested to me that I should use threading/multithreading, but that looks kinda complicated and I can't quite figure it out.

Is there a better way to do it or is threading the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of time passed since a certain point by subtracting the start time from the current time. You can then update the timer value with this (if you have a lot of other code running in between this will become slower so you might want to round it).

```
import time

start = time.time()
while doing_stuff:
     do_stuff()
     GUI.update_timer(time.time() - start)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why threading is not a good idea. For one, if you have complex computations to run in your code, threading will enhance the performance by running your code and the timer in the background in tandem. Here's something that may help illustrate my point with a simple function to square numbers:

```
import time
import threading

def square():
    start_time = time.time()
    x = int(input('Enter number: '))
    squared = x*x
    print('Square is: %s ' %squared)
    print('Time elapsed: %s seconds' %(time.time() - start_time))


set_thread = threading.Thread(target=square) #set Thread() to run on square() function

set_thread.start()

#Output:
Enter number: 5
Square is: 25 
Time elapsed: 1.4820027351379395 seconds
```

Of course, the simple function above may take only a few seconds. The timer begins when the function is called and stops when the code in the `square()` block has run. But imagine a situation where your code has much more complex computations such as insert multiple values into a database or sort a large list of data and write to a file at the same time.